# KMZ import does not create columns in attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, kmz

I would like to import a [KMZ file with data](https://www.see.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/fg10/Projekte/Ergebnisse/Wave_new/BIER.KMZ) on [basin internal evaporation recycling](https://www.see.tu-berlin.de/menue/forschung/ergebnisse/wave/) into QGIS.

However when I import the KMZ file into QGIS, the relevant data (Bier-jan, BIER-feb, ...) is not added in individual columns of the attribute table but rather all values are added into one single column with together with html syntax.

[image]

The cell content of cells in the 'description' column looks is as follows:

```
    <html xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

<head>

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

</head>

<body style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;overflow:auto;background:#FFFFFF;">

<table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;padding:3px 3px 3px 3px">

<tr style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background:#9CBCE2">

<td></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>

<table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-spacing:0px; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px">

<tr>

<td>BIER-jan</td>

<td>0,021422</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<td>BIER-feb</td>

<td>0,02088</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>BIER-mar</td>

<td>0,019949</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<td>BIER-apr</td>

<td>0,013789</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>BIER-may</td>

<td>0,011909</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<td>BIER-jun</td>

<td>0,007501</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>BIER-jul</td>

<td>0,007841</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<td>BIER-aug</td>

<td>0,005692</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>BIER-sep</td>

<td>0,005994</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<td>BIER-oct</td>

<td>0,00542</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>BIER-nov</td>

<td>0,009162</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<td>BIER-dec</td>

<td>0,016144</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>BIER-annual</td>

<td>0,013681</td>

</tr>

</table>

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

How can I import the KMZ file and add the individual data sets (BIER-jan, BIER-feb, ... ) to dedicated columns in the attribute table?

I already tried to extract the respective numbers with string extraction and string position via the field calculator but a lot cells ended up with a NULL values.
... something like *extracting the eight values after the start position of BIER-jan+syntax*

```
 substr(description,strpos(description,'BIER-jan')+17,8)
```

There is also an [online converter](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/) which does the job but it is limited to 5MB per month.